# Implementing equivalence in Biopython's PDB module

Tags: python, biopython

#### Background

In the `PDB` module of Biopython, [PDB structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protein_Data_Bank) are parsed into `Structure` objects, which store the components of the structure in a SMCRA archiecture  (Structure/Model/Chain/Residue/Atom). Each level of this hierarchy is represented by an object that inherits the `Entity` container class.

#### Equivalence

My problem is that at no point can any two Entity objects be equal.

Structures built from the same file are not equal:

```py
>>> from Bio import PDB
>>> parser = PDB.PDBParser()
>>> struct1 = parser.get_structure("1hgg", "pdb1hgg.ent")
>>> struct2 = parser.get_structure("1hgg", "pdb1hgg.ent")
>>> struct1 == struct2
False
```

Residues within that structure are not equal:

```py
>>> first_res1 = struct1.get_residues().next()
>>> first_res2 = struct2.get_residues().next()
>>> first_res1 == first_res2
False
```

And so on.

If we were to parse the same PDB file separately, at no point could any of the `Entity` objects within the structures be equal.

#### Solution

The obvious solution to this problem is to never parse the same PDB file twice. Then, we have object identity and thus, equivalence. However, this answer seems incomplete to me.

Each `Entity` object can return an identification tuple with [`get_full_id()`](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.PDB.Entity.Entity-class.html#get_full_id). This method gives all id's from the top object down; it should be unique for each `Entity` within a structure, and unique across all structures if the proper PDB id was supplied when constructing the `Structure` object.

My solution for testing `Entity` equivalence is merely to compare this full id. That is:

```py
def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.get_full_id() == other.get_full_id()
```

#### Question

At this point, I'm asking if my implementation of `Entity` equivalence is sensible.

- Are false positives (e.g. differing structures that were supplied the same PDB id) a worry?
- Is it better to simply manually compare the full id's whenever we need to test equivalence?
- And is there any reason why `__eq__` was left unimplemented within the `PDB` module?

Comment: False positive are a massive worry. What about where you have modified one of the entities (e.g. change its positions), but the ID would be the same.

Comment: So is avoiding rebuilding the same structure (and therefore, relying on object identity for equivalence) how you would solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One common reason for not defining an `__eq__` is that it makes things unhashable (so you can't use them as dictionary keys or put them in sets), unless you also define a consistent `__hash__` function, **and** your objects are immutable.

By default `__hash__` for objects just uses the ID, which works even for mutable objects, since the ID never changes. But if you define a custom `__eq__`, you can't keep hashing by ID, or you'll get a situation where two objects can compare as equal but have different hashes, which is inconsistent with how hashing is supposed to work. So you have to define a custom `__hash__` function (which you can do), but then if your object is mutable, you can't/shouldn't really do *that*, either, so you'll just have an unhashable object.  Which may be all right for you.

See more info in the python docs [here](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__).

So you can use a custom `__eq__` as long as you don't need your objects to be hashable, or if they're immutable; otherwise things get more complicated.  Or you could just leave `__eq__` alone and name your full ID comparison function something else, so as to not break hashability.

I don't know enough about what PDB IDs mean (in particular, whether false positives are possible) to tell whether your `__eq__` implementation is reasonable from that standpoint.

Comment: Thank you- I am aware of the `__eq__`/`__hash__` issue. I should have added that as a temporary fix, I was also hashing by the `full_id` of an Entity (although that's a tremendously bad idea).

Comment: @David - Ah, okay. Sorry for making you read all that, then. ;) Still, that's my best guess as to why `__eq__` was unimplemented in PDB, which was one of your questions.